# Do I need a transit visa for a 4h20min transit at Heathrow Airport?

Tags: visas, uk, transit

I wish to know if I will need a transit visa to pass through Heathrow Airport. I will be visiting my kid sister in Spain on Friday August 19, 2016 using Norwegian Airlines to be back again in Denmark Sunday August 21, 2016 using British Airways.

My transit time is 4 hours 20 minutes at Heathrow Airport before my departure to Denmark where I have been living for 16 years and have a permanent resident.

Comment: Any reason for the downvotes besides lack of punctuation and bad spelling ?